# Как создать очередь ajax запросов?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Допустим есть объект url адресов, нужно циклично по ним пройтись, но нужно ждать пока не пришел ответ в предыдущего, с интервалом 5 секунд

```html
<button>Запустить</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var urls = {
    1: {url: 'https://google.com/'},
    2: {url: 'https://yandex.com/'},
    3: {url: 'https://yahoo.com/'}
  };

  function getUrl(){
    $.each(urls, function(i, elem){
      $.ajax({
        url: elem.url,
        beforeSend: function(){
          console.log('Получение ответа от: '+ elem.url +' ...');
        }
      })
      .always(function(data){
        console.log('Получен ответ от: '+ elem.url);
      });
      setTimeout(function(){}, 5000);
    });
  }

  $("button").on('click', function(){
    getUrl();
  });
});
</script>
```

Должно быть так

```
Получение ответа от: https://google.com/ ...
Получен ответ от: https://google.com/

// ждем 5 секунд
Получение ответа от: https://yandex.com/ ...
Получен ответ от: https://yandex.com/

// ждем 5 секунд
Получение ответа от: https://yahoo.com/ ...
Получен ответ от: https://yahoo.com/
```

А выводит это все сразу, нет ожидания 5 секунд:

```
Получение ответа от: https://google.com/ ...
Получение ответа от: https://yandex.com/ ...
Получение ответа от: https://yahoo.com/ ...
Получен ответ от: https://google.com/
Получен ответ от: https://yandex.com/
Получен ответ от: https://yahoo.com/
```

Comment: смотрите в сторону `Promise`

Comment: Может сделать запрос синхронным?

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц, `async: false` вроде как `deprecated`

Comment: https://caolan.github.io/async/

Answer (score 1):

```html
<button>Запустить</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var urls = {
      1: { url: 'https://google.com/' },
      2: { url: 'https://yandex.com/' },
      3: { url: 'https://yahoo.com/' }
    };

    function getUrls() {
      var keys = Object.keys(urls);
      getOneUrl(0);
      
      function getOneUrl(index) {
        $.ajax({
            url: urls[keys[index]].url,
            beforeSend: function() {
              console.log('Получение ответа от: ' + urls[keys[index]].url + ' ...');
            }
          })
          .always(function(data) {
            console.log('Получен ответ от: ' + urls[keys[index]].url);
            if (index < keys.length - 1) {
              console.log("ждем 5 секунд");
              setTimeout(getOneUrl, 5000, index + 1);
            }
          });
      }
    }

    $("button").on('click', function() {
      getUrls();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<button>Запустить</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var urls = {
      1: { url: 'https://google.com/' },
      2: { url: 'https://yandex.com/' },
      3: { url: 'https://yahoo.com/' }
    };

    var size = Object.keys(urls).length;

 function getUrl(){

    $.each(urls, function(i, elem){

    setTimeout(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: elem.url,
        beforeSend: function(){
          console.log('Получение ответа от: '+ elem.url +' ...');
        }
      })
      .always(function(data){
        console.log('Получен ответ от: '+ elem.url);
        if (i < size)
          console.log("ждем 5 секунд");
        else
          console.log("Конец");
      });
      
    }, 5000*(i-1));
    });
   
  }
    $("button").on('click', function() {
      getUrl();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Роман, не ожидал от Вас - все `ajax`-ы выстрелят одновременно - через пять секунд.

Comment: @Igor Да, хотел что-то наподобие, но бросил...